# Flask (Python): Pass input as parameter to function of different route with fixed URL

Tags: python, flask

How do I get the user input submitted on the form to be displayed on a fixed URL?

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def main():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        msg = request.form['message']
        return redirect(url_for('display_msg', msg=msg))
    else:
        return form


@app.route('/msg')
def display_msg(msg):
    return msg
```

When submitting the form, I get the following error:

TypeError: display_msg() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'

This code actually works fine if I initialize `msg` as a global variable and then do `global msg` at the top of `main`, but it will not allow me to pass `msg` as a parameter to `display_msg`.

Another way this will work is if I change `@app.route('/msg')` to `@app.route('/<string:msg>')`, but this will change the URL to whatever the user submitted on the form which is not what I want. I want the URL to be fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the data from *msg* is already stored in the request object, rather than passing it as a parameter to *display_msg*, it can be accessed as follows:

```
@app.route('/msg')
def display_msg():
    return request.args.get('msg')
```

The TypeError occurred because the keyword arguments for *url_for* are passed to the request object and not as parameters to *display_msg*.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the *msg* parameter:

```
@app.route('/msg/<msg>')
def display_msg(msg):
    return msg
```

Comment: I want the URL for display_msg to be the same regardless of what the user inputs on the form. Please read the last few lines of my post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global variable to store the message and return to a fixed url.

**Edit: I updated `display_msg()` to use a default argument.**

```
global_msg = ""
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def main():
    global global_msg
    if request.method == 'POST':
        global_msg = request.form['message']
        return redirect(url_for('display_msg'))
    else:
        return form


@app.route('/msg')
def display_msg(msg = global_msg):
    return msg
```

Hope this helped you.

> NOTE:Please don't use this answer! what happens when multiple clients connect to your server and access the same route at once! they will actually share data between then!

Comment: Yes, I know that already. I'm asking why it doesn't work when I pass it locally as a parameter.

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to get away from global member method? I modified the answer to accept direct calls to `display_msg()` by using default arguments.

Comment: Well, because it's generally good practice to avoid using global variables when possible. See my answer below.

Comment: Please don't use this answer! what happens when multiple clients connect to your server and access the same route at once! they will actually share data between then!